# Nofollow link on footer

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I have added the following code for NoFollow for SEO purposes -

**Social Widget**

```
echo '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="'.$ref_url.'" class="preloading_background  avia_partner1 link_list_item'.$kriesiaddwidget.' '.$firsttitle.'" >'.$image_url.'</a>';
if($this->add_cont == 2) echo '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="'.$ref_url2.'" class="preloading_background avia_partner2 link_list_item'.$kriesiaddwidget.' '.$firsttitle.'" >'.$image_url2.'</a>';
```

**Footer**

```
$kriesi_at_backlink =   apply_filters("kriesi_backlink", " - <a href='http://kriesi.at'  rel='nofollow'>Enfold Theme by Kriesi</a>");
```

However, when I check on console it doesn't seem to show??

Link to the site is - http://www.haramaintours.com/

Comment: What doesn't seem to show? I can see the rel="nofollow" on the Enfold Theme by Kriesi in the source.

Comment: What is exact problem, there is nofollow tag on page

Comment: @Armin it doesnt show on the console in the inspection tool

Comment: @OleHaugset It doesn't seem to show on the console when i inspect element

Comment: It does show: https://pasteboard.co/Hwe3WW3.png

Comment: it is showing in console

Comment: Sorry about this but I am new to coding and seo. Is there a way to know if the no follow link is working? @OleHaugset

Comment: @charankumar Sorry about this but I am new to coding and seo. Is there a way to know if the no follow link is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working.

If you want to check,

open website and press CTRL + U, this will load the source code.

Then CTRL + F, this will open search, then type **rel="nofollow"** in search

You will get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, it was a cached issue. Working now